# Any way in Blender to project an edge from a vertex, along an axis?

Tags: vertices

Super beginner question:  I'm trying to do something in Blender that's relatively easy in a different program I use.  I'm trying to project a line from a vertex (point 1 below) to an edge (point 2), such that it follows one of the major axes to get there (X,Y,Z).  Where it intersects, I'd like to add another vertex.  I've tried the knife tool, but this doesn't appear to be getting me the results I need.

Another question:  The picture is a wall with a cutout in it (bathroom with shampoo shelf).  The whole reason I started wondering this is because it appears Blender will not let that shelf exist within the plane it is on unless there are at minimum of 2 edges connecting it to that plane (as there are below it here).  I realize this is likely super basic behavior, just wondering why that must be.  Is that to avoid creating ngons?

[image]

Comment: First question (one question at a time): Select the edge.  Snap cursor to selection.  Set orientation to global ("major axis" presumably means global axes?), pivot point to cursor.  Select vert you want to project, e extrude enter, s x 0 enter (to move onto the cursor exactly, constrained by the global X axis line containing the point.)

Comment: What is it about the knife tool that is not working? If you press C when "cutting", with the knife, it will snap the cut line to the nearest major axis. Combine that with the ortho camera angles (Numpad 1,3,7  for front, side and top, or 9 to flip any of the first 3 by 180) and you can make precise, right angle cuts.

Comment: Thank you Nathan!  That worked.  Christopher, I had tried that, but C was only ever parallel to what I saw, depending on how it was rotated.  I didn't think to use the camera angles to lock in the global axes.  Great idea.